# Eclipse content assist improvement

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, autocomplete, content-management

Is it possible to make content assistant work as Netbeans code completion during typing "new "? I mean that Netbeans suggests all possible classes that fit to the type requirements including extending classes. Eclipse suggest only exact classes that fit to the required type.
Here is example comparison:
http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/360/comparisons.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NB code-completion/content assist is driven by the projects, libraries and jars/folders that the project depends on.  I would assume that Eclipse does something similar, so the first step to try to resolve this is to make sure your project has the classes on its project class path.